# build.gradle copy task after building project

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, gradle, android-studio

I am developing an app with the Java version of Google App Engine in Android Studio. In my backend I load a .csv file from

*Projectpath\backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF\classes*

with

```
FacilityImporter.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

in order to import it to my Data Store. 
When testing on my local backend, I manually move the .csv file to the classes folder after starting the backend. Now I want to do the same when I deploy the backend on the Google servers, but I have no idea how to do so.

I guess there should be a way of doing so by adding it to some build file. I'd be very grateful if someone could point me to a solution.

EDIT: 
I figured out, that I have to edit my build.gradle of the backend module.
I wrote a copy task, but it still doesn't work.
Imo either the task is executed too early, so that the entire classes folder gets overwritten after copying the .csv or there is something wrong with my filepaths.

```
task copyTask(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/main/java/ase2014/at/appname/backend/util/FacilityImporter'
    into 'build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/classes'
    include '**/*.csv'
}
```

Sorry for asking such trivial questions, but this is the first time that I have to deal with gradle build files.

Comment: You should make a new question when a new issue occurs after solving your first issue.

Comment: I only let you know this because I came here looking to answer your issue and found it hard to figure out what state your code is currently in or what exactly your current problem is.